# How to call a function from any class by a pointer to it?

Tags: c++, pointers, design-patterns

I'm building an engine. I need to create a `Timer` class which will call a function by a pointer from a separate class. For example:

```
class MyTimer {
public:
    void setTimeoutFunction( _pointer_, unsigned short timeoutMs ) {
        // here we need to have a opportunity to store a _pointer_ to a function
    }
    void tickTimer() {
        ...
        // here I need to call a function by a pointer
        ...
    }
};

// Main class:
class MyAnyClass {
public:
    void start() {
        MyTimer myTimer;
        myTimer.setTimeoutFunction( startThisFunc, 1500 ); // 1500ms = 1.5s
        while ( true ) {
            myTimer.tickTimer();
        }
    }
    void startThisFunc() { ... }
}
```

In summation, how do you store a pointer to a function which belongs to some class and call that function by a pointer?

Comment: This question is too broad to get a good answer but maybe you should start looking at [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) with which you can archive what you want.

Comment: Will you always have one private timer for only one object at a time, or will a single timer object need to be able to handle multiple objects of different types?

Comment: @KerrekSB I need one timer for one object at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, I might recommend making the timer a class *template*:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyTimer
{
    using FuncPtr = void (T::*)();

    MyTimer(FuncPtr ptr, T * obj, unsigned int timeout_ms)
    : ptr_(ptr), obj_(obj), timeout_ms_(timeout_ms) {}

    void tickTimer()
    {
        (obj_->*ptr_)();
    }

    FuncPtr ptr_;
    T * obj_;
    unsigned int timeout_ms_;
};
```

Usage:

```
struct MyAnyClass
{
    void start()
    {
        MyTimer<MyAnyClass> myTimer(&MyAnyClass::startThisFunc, this, 1500);
        while (true) { myTimer.tickTimer(); }
    }

    void startThisFunc() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: Wow, that's a cool trick. Thanks! Is it possible to use somehow this sample without "using" keyword? I think it's C++11 style but unfortunately I can't currently use C++11.

Comment: Here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias i found a sample: `using func = void (*) (int,int);` -- type alias, identical to `typedef void (*func)(int, int);`
I think that's what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can use std::function. A good guide on using it is here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

I created a new code snippet only containing the case you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    void print_add(int i) const { std::cout << num_+i << '\n'; }
    int num_;
};


int main()
{
  // store a call to a member function
    std::function<void(const Foo&, int)> f_add_display = &Foo::print_add;
    const Foo foo(314159);
    f_add_display(foo, 1);

    return 0;
}
```